# How to get userData after signup with firebase (with email and password)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have the Code:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password).catch(function(error) {
            if(error) {
                console.log("error!");
            }
            else {



            }

        });
//I need the var userData.uid
firebase.database().ref("users/"+userData.uid).set({
                email: user.email,
                displayName: user.displayname
                });
```

but how can I get the userData (user uid) if the signup was successful?

Comment: [`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword) returns a promise that resolves with the [`User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User). So use `then(function (user) { console.log(user.uid); })` before your `catch`.

Answer (score 3):

This will help you.

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
   .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.uid);

      firebase.database().ref("users/"+response.uid).set({
         email: user.email,
         displayName: user.displayname
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

also with validation try catch

```
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then(function(response) {
         console.log(response);
         alert(response.uid);
         if(response.uid){
           alert('SignUp success');
            firebase.database().ref("users/"+response.uid).set({
               email: user.email,
               displayName: user.displayname
               alert(email);
            });
         }


   }
 ).catch(function(error){
   var errorCode = error.code;
   var errorMessage = error.message;
   if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
     $.toast({ heading: ' Notification', text: errorMessage, position: 'top-right', loaderBg: '#ff6849', icon: 'error',  hideAfter: 3000,stack: 6 });
       return false;
   }

 });
```